# PyQt ComboBox results not working in MySQL

Tags: python, pyqt, mysql-python

I am writing a program in which two variables are selected from QCombobBoxes which are populated with results from a MySQL query.  I then take these variable and insert them into a MySQLdb statement that inserts the variables into a different MySQL table.  The first variable works fine, however on the second I get this error,

```
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The code is identical for both variables, with the exception of different names

```
name = str(self.item_name.currentText())
cur.execute("SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE name = '%s';"), name  
db.commit()
results = cur.fetchone()
item_name = results[0]

personnel_name = str(self.purchaser_name.currentText())
cur.execute("SELECT personnel_id FROM Personnel WHERE name = '%s';"), personnel_name  
db.commit()
results = cur.fetchone()
purchaser_id = results[0]
```

After playing with it, it looks like `cur.execute("SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE name = '%s';"), name` is inserting an extra pair of quotation marks around the value that replaces `%s`  Does anyone know why it's doing this and how to stop it?  I coded both variables exactly the same, and it seems that `name` is getting an extra pair of quotes from MySQL

This is code that populates QComboBox:

```
    #Get list of items currently in the database
    cur = db.cursor()
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM Items")
    db.commit()
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for name in results:
        self.item_name.addItem(name[0])

    #Get list of purchaser names
    cur.execute("SELECT name FROM Personnel")
    db.commit()
    results = cur.fetchall()
    for name in results:
        self.purchaser_name.addItem(name[0])
```

If I manually insert a variable, it works fine.  ex: `cur.execute("SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE name = 'Wire';")`  Only when I use string formatting with `%s` does the error occurr.

Comment: I'm using Python 2.7.  This may be wrong, but I learned to use `%` in these situations.

Comment: should it be `cur.execute("SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE name = '%s';", (name,))` ... its possible the mysql driver automatically encloses %s as a quoted string

Answer (score 0):

```
c.execute("SELECT * FROM sometable WHERE some_condition=?","My Condition")
```

you should always use the ? placeholders for this kind of thing

[edit]

try 1. `cur.execute("SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE name = '%s';"%(name,))`

or 2. `cur.execute("SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE name = %s;", (name,))`

from my brief reading, I think that mysql driver will automatically quote %s arguments
my conclusion is that `cur.execute("SELECT item_id FROM Items WHERE name = %s;", (name,))` is the most correct way to do this(to avoid injection etc).

Comment: I tried this, experienced a MySQL syntax error.  The placeholder failed.  `1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '?' at line 1"`  I used almost the exact same code I had been using for the other variable and it worked fine.